# Files.newDirectoryStream(path) does not return files recursively

Tags: java, nio

I m expecting to see a list of all files located under path d:/test folder. However, I can only get the files directly under that folder, but not recursively. 
Code:

```
        String folder = "D:/test";
        Path path = fs.getPath(folder);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {  
            for (Path p : directoryStream) {
                System.out.println(p.getFileName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
```

result:

```
a.txt
folder
```

folder structure:
[image]

Comment: Did you mean *recursively* instead of *iteratively*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to this extending your own logic :

```
public static void printFileNamesRecursively(String path){
    Path yourPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path);

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(yourPath))           {  
            for (Path p : directoryStream) {
                System.out.println(p.getFileName());
                if(p.toFile().isDirectory()){

                    printFileNamesRecursively(p.toString());
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Files::newDirectoryStream` are meant to behave like that. If you want to *recursively* retrieve all directories and  files in the given directory and its sub-directories, you will need `Files::walk` or `Files::walkFileTree`. For example (I assume you use Java 8):

```
Path path = //...
try {
    Files.walk(path).map(Path::getFileName).forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so I guess @Rambler's answer would be a "how to do it" in java 7?

Comment: @Tiina Certainly. But beware that if your directory is very, very deep, or contains a loop (via symbolic/hard links), you will end up with an StackOverFlowExcepetion. If your software may work with unknown directory, you may need to modify how it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right behavior for DirectoryStream. Instead, You can use **org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils** to enumerate the files recursively.